# Setting the SMTP_OUT_PARAMETER in 10G at runtime

Tags: oracle-10g-r2

I am writing a procedure that will send mail from oracle 10g. I have installed the UTL_MAIL and UTL_SMTP packages and configured the SMTP_OUT_SERVER parameter. However the requirement is that the SMTP server address be chosen at runtime. How do I resolve the issue.??

Comment: Can't you just do `execute immediate 'ALTER SYSTEM SET smtp_out_server = <value> SCOPE = both';` in your stored procedure?

Comment: That parameter is not modifiable

Comment: That's what the documentation says, but in my experience it just works. Go figure.

Comment: The other thing the OP will need to be aware of is the need to set a network ACL which will allow all of the SMTP servers to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs, you cannot selectively choose from multiple SMTP_OUT_SERVER values. Here's how that parameter works:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams230.htm#REFRN10241

> SMTP_OUT_SERVER specifies the SMTP host and port to which UTL_MAIL delivers out-bound E-mail. Multiple servers may be specified, separated by commas.
>
> If the first server in the list is unavailable, then UTL_MAIL tries the second server, and so on.

It looks like you will need to manage this requirement externally.

Comment: Surely you can just run `execute immediate 'ALTER SYSTEM SET smtp_out_server = new.server.com SCOPE = both';` ?

Comment: Nope. As per the above doc, the parameter is not modifiable. This means you need to restart the database to change the value.

Comment: Oh? I've always done it on the fly and never noticed a need to restart or Oracle complaining about `scope = both`. I just tested it on 11.2 by changing my `smtp_out_server` to "blah" and `utl_mail.send` failed. When I changed it back again, the mail sent fine. No restarting, just using `scope = both`. I don't recall doing anything differently when we were still using 10G, either.

Comment: Well if it works, then the docs are wrong.

Comment: I think there may be a difference between testing from sqlplus or SQLDeveloper using `exec utl_mail.send(...` versus having a stored procedure run the same command (seems to work for the former, not the latter, until the database is shutdown and restarted).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did not even need to run `'ALTER SYSTEM SET smtp_out_server = new.server.com SCOPE = both';`

I just passed the host name via xml and kept a default host name in config table in case the xml is blank.

Comment: "via XML"? What do you mean? Please show as an example of what you did.